# Converting Discrete Random Variables to Continous

Tags: continuity, normal-distribution, binomial-distribution

The discrete random variable H takes values 1, 2, 3 and 4.

It is given that:

[image]

[image]

The mean of a random sample of 50 observations of [image] is denoted by [image].

Use a suitable approximation to find [image]

I understand that the appropriate thing to do here is to use a normal approximation to the binomial one, N(2.5, 0.025). However, I don't understand why exactly the continuity correction applied is:

[image]

Namely the 2.59 part. I understand generally to change discrete binomial variables into continuous normal, you would have to first turn a strict inequality into an unstrict one and then extend the range of the inequality by 0.5, but I'm just a bit unsure about this specific example!

Comment: Where does this come from - a text book? Actually the Central Limit Theorem should be applied, not the Normal approximation to the Binomial...

Comment: Hi - it's actually a past exam paper for S2 OCR, exam season coming up!

Comment: Which paper? Is this from the mark scheme?

Comment: It's Q4 of this:
http://pmt.physicsandmathstutor.com/download/Maths/A-level/S2/Papers-OCR/January%202012%20QP%20-%20S2%20OCR.pdf

And the mark scheme:
http://pmt.physicsandmathstutor.com/download/Maths/A-level/S2/Papers-OCR/January%202012%20MS%20-%20S2%20OCR.pdf

Comment: Hi - yes, the mark scheme uses 2.59. I thought to just use 2.6

"Standardise 2.59 or 2.61, with square root (1.25/50)"

Comment: I agree with you, and I note that they allow an answer whch uses 2.6. Maybe there's something in the OCR textbook which explains their reasons for this but I can't see it's really necessary